# TypeError: object() takes no parameters (trex dino bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i solve this problem please tell me what to do 
this i am not able to figure out this problem. so please do tell me how to solve this in simple words.

```
import time

from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui

class Cordinates():
    replayBtn = (340,420)
    dinosaur = (422,170)
    #215= xcordinate to check for tree

def restartGame():
    pyautogui.click(Cordinates.replayBtn)

def pressSapce():
    pyautogui.keyDown('space')
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print("Jump")
pyautogui.KeyUp('space')

restartGame()
time.sleep(1)
pressSapce()
```

---

after runing i get

---

```
C:\Users\Pranav\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/Pranav/PycharmProjects/untitled1/bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
Jump
File "C:/Users/Pranav/PycharmProjects/untitled1/bot.py", line 22, in <module>
pressSapce()
File "C:/Users/Pranav/PycharmProjects/untitled1/bot.py", line 18, in pressSapce
    pyautogui.KeyUp('space')
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

how to solve :-

```
pyautogui.KeyUp('space')
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

what do you mean by the above message

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `keyUp` not `KeyUp` with capital letter [docs](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html?highlight=keyup#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions)

```
pyautogui.keyUp('space')
```

Answer (score 1):

`pyautogui.KeyUp('space')`

is supposed to be

`pyautogui.keyUp('space')`

That should fix your problem.